# c# filling up empty records

Tags: c#, space, fill

need some help with my foreach to recongonize the empty record and fill the gap with "-";

let's say we have 30min, 45min, 90min, 120min and not 60min in the case:

It can count the total records of each id, let's say the maximum is 5, 30min, 45min, 60min, 90min and 120min.

if there are 3, then it could check which is missing and than can fill with "-".

Same ideia of the script.

```
List<Treatment> treatment = new List<Treatment>();
treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 11, duration = "30", price = 30 });
treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 11, duration = "45", price = 45 });
treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 11, duration = "60", price = 60 });
treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 2, duration = "30", price = 30 });
//treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 2, duration = "45", price = 45 });
treatment.Add(new Treatment { id = 1, treatmentNameId = 2, duration = "60", price = 60 });

var newList = (from t in treatment
                         select t)
                         .AsQueryable().ToList();

List<List> newList= new List<List>();
foreach (var item in newList) 
{       
    if (item.duration == "30") 
    {
        newList.Add(new List {  treatmentNameId = item.treatmentNameId, thirtyMin = "30" });
    }

    if (item.duration == "45") 
    {
        newList.Add(new List {  treatmentNameId = item.treatmentNameId, fortyFive= "45" });  
    }                

    if (item.duration == "60") 
    {
        newList.Add(new List {  treatmentNameId = item.treatmentNameId, sixty= "60" });         
    }  
}
```

The end result should like something as,

```
id:1  30, 45, 60, -
id:2  30, - , 60, 90
id:3  - , 45, -, 90
```

etc...

Many many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide a very detailed explanation of all this, but conceptually I'm just grouping by treatmentNameId and then doing something very similar to an outer join in SQL. If the group join comes up empty for the duration, I'm selecting '-' instead of the duration. Using anonymous types for brevity.

```
        var durations = new[] {"15", "30", "45", "60"};

        var results = treatments
            .GroupBy(t => t.treatmentNameId).Select(group => new
            {
                treatmentNameId = group.Key,
                durations = durations.GroupJoin(group, s => s, g => g.duration,
                    (s, grouping) => !grouping.Any() ? "-" : s)
            });

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.treatmentNameId + ": " + string.Join(", ", result.durations));
        }
```

This results in:

```
11: -, 30, 45, 60
2: -, 30, -, 60
```

If you have problems with something more specific, I'd be happy to explain further.